# How to get directory paths as strings after using glob like Dir constructor?

Tags: ruby, glob

I intend to pass to a Dir constructor a string representing a glob matching all directories such as `/**/*` so I can receive a array of Dirs representing the matched directories.

How can I take the paths of those Dirs as strings? Is that possible to be done without invoking `Dir.chdir` and without iterating over all the files contained in those directories?

EDIT: After reading the first answer I plan on testing this snippet, just to print the returned entity of `glob()` method:

```
def processRemappingConfig(configString)
   configLineArray = line.split("=>").each{ |entry| entry.chomp!;}
   if configLineArray[0].match(/(\*\*)+/) then
      #TODO:HOW TO Expand dirname path and get list of paths
      puts Dir.glob(configLineArray[0]);
   end
end
```

Where `configString` will be `/**/$currLogicSrcProjDirName=>/$currLogicSrcProjDirName`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a trailing slash to the glob pattern, you'll get back only directories, rather than directories and files:

```
directories = Dir.glob("/**/*/")
```

That will get you a simple array of strings with all the directory names.